# I am having trouble using an operator= overload with a static member function. Is there something wrong in the code?

Tags: c++

I have an assignment operator overload that seems to work fine and I have static member function defined in a Pointer class that returns a class of type Pointer which also seems to work fine but when they are used together it throws a conversion error even though they are the same type.

e.g.

```
Pointer<float> a;
a = Pointer<float>::New(3.1415); //ERROR
```

so it actually works fine when the assignment operator overload argument is passed by reference, but when I switch it to be passed by value it throws a compiler error.

```
//header
namespace Dexter {
template <class T>
class Pointer {
private:
    T* m_raw_pointer;
    bool m_is_owner;
public:

    Pointer();
    Pointer(T);
    ~Pointer();

    static Pointer<T> New(T);
    virtual void Delete();

    void operator=(Pointer<T>&);
    T operator*();
};
};

//implementation
template <class T> Dexter::Pointer<T> Dexter::Pointer<T>::New(T val) {
Pointer<T> temp(val);
temp.m_is_owner = false;
return temp;
}
template <class T> void Dexter::Pointer<T>::Delete() {

if (m_raw_pointer != NULL && m_is_owner) {
    delete m_raw_pointer;
    m_raw_pointer = NULL;
    m_is_owner = false;
}
}

template <class T> void Dexter::Pointer<T>::operator=(Pointer<T>& obj) {
Delete();

m_raw_pointer = obj.m_raw_pointer;
obj.m_is_owner = false;
m_is_owner = true;
}

//main.cpp
Dexter::Pointer<float> a(1.616);
a = Dexter::Pointer<float>::New(3.1415); //ERROR: conversion type
```

expected results:

```
*a.m_raw_pointer = 3.1415;
```

actual results:

`Error  C2679   binary '=': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'Dexter::Pointer<float>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)  Dexter`

Comment: Please post complete error message. Also `operator =` should typically accept either a reference to const object or an rvalue reference to non-const object and you forgot to provide copy / move constructors.

Comment: You seem to be trying to reinvent `std::unique_ptr`. Is there a reason you cannot use the real deal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `operator=(Pointer<T>&)` takes its argument by a non-const reference, which means it cannot accept a temporary. But `Pointer<float>::New(3.1415)` does in fact return a temporary.

You seem to want a move-assignment operator, rather than a copy-assignment one (as yours modifies the source of the copy). Such a function would take its argument by rvalue reference, `operator=(Pointer<T>&&)` (note two ampersands).